Pi Camera Breaking
I have a raspberry pi 4 and I am trying to connect a Camera Module 3 to the board. The Camera will work for a while, and then will stop working and will be bricked. The only time that I can see it happened right after I did a specific thing was when I installed some python libraries onto the pi. The only libraries that would interact with the camera were opencv and picamera2.
This happened a few other times on some other boards, and they would just brick randomly and not work again. To test the cameras, I use libcamera-hello, and it says that there is no camera that is connected to the pi, when the camera is obviously plugged in.
I have run sudo apt-get update and upgrade, and that didn't fix anything.
How to determine the cause of the problem?

Have you read this? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=362707

I assume you are using Pi OS Bookworm 64bit?

how many cameras have you "bricked"? Where do you buy them from?
